# transfering a directory which is not in the files via ansible roles

Tags: ansible, copy, roles

I am using a role and my directory looks like this:

```
|_ ansible/
|  |_ role1/
|  |   |_ tasks/
|  |   |_ templates/
|  |_ playbook.yml
|
|_target_directory/
```

I want to copy `target_directory` to remote server by relative path
my code looks like this:

```
copy:
  src: ../target_directory
  dest: ...
```

but after running Ansible I faced that Ansible was looking for `target_directory` under `role1/file/../target_directory` and showed errors.

How can I transfer `target_directory` to my remote server? (I cannot use absolute paths)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rounded this problem by `ansible_dir`:

```
copy:
  src: "{{playbook_dir}}/../target_directory"
  dest: ...
```